# Как взять Id из Json?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

Я использую плагин [datatables](https://datatables.net/), чтоб получить данные из бд в таблицу, я делаю `ajax` запрос и получаю `json objects`:

Так я получаю нужные данные из бд и передаю их во View:

```
 public ActionResult dataTablesData (BLL.Model.jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
        {
            var model = newsDbProv.GetAllData(param.iDisplayStart, param.iDisplayLength, param.iSortCol_0, param.sSortDir_0, param.sSearch);

            var result = model.News.ConvertAll(x => new {
                x.Id,
                x.FullTitle,
                x.FullArticle            
            });

            return Json(new {
                sEcho = param.sEcho,
                iTotalRecords = model.iTotalRecords,
                iTotalDisplayRecords = model.iTotalRecords,
                aaData = result


            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Вот, что происходить во View:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="myTable">
    <thead style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 10px" >Id</td>
            <td style="width: 200px">Title</td>
            <td>Article</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "dataTablesData",

            columns: [
                { data: 'Id' },
                { data: 'FullTitle' },
                { data: 'FullArticle' }
            ],
            "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
            select: {
                style: 'single'
            },
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Мне надо сделать кнопки редактирования и удаления, по нажатию на кнопку должен передаваться Id в контроллер.

**Вопрос:** Как получить id из этой таблицы?

Comment: Как идея: завести четвертую колонку, и в ней сделать ссылки  на "~/Articles/Edit/" + Id, который вы получаете в json

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев а где взять этот Id? Как его вытащить из json?

Comment: вот же он columns: [
                { data: 'Id' }

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев это указатель, куда будут поступать данные из Json с именем Id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне удалось решить свою проблему с помощь плагина [jQuery Redirect](https://github.com/mgalante/jquery.redirect) + ajax запрос.

Я добавил две кнопки:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="btn-edit">Edit</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="btn-delete">Delete</button>
```

Далее написал вот такой код:

```
$('#btn-delete').click(function () {
    var agreement = confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete this row?');
    var data = table.row('.selected').data().Id;
    if (agreement) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Delete/' + data,
            success: function () {
                table.rows($('#myTable tr.active')).remove().draw(false);
            }
        });
    }
});


$('#btn-edit').click(function () {
    var data = table.row('.selected').data().Id;
    $.redirect("Edit", { id: data }, "GET");
});
```

Так же у плагина [datatables](https://datatables.net/) есть фреймовик [editor](https://editor.datatables.net/) для удаления и редактирования данных, но он платный.